# how to update an instance to database in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to update an instance which is in database, session.merge() does not work, then, which function should be used and how to code?

Comment: ``commit``? usually we do ``DBSession.add(instance)`` and if you want immediate commit we call commit.

Comment: session.add(instance) will create another instance in database with dirrerent primarykey, i just want to modify the instance with the same primarylkey in database. it is just updating. if just update one column, we can use update(), but how to update an entity!

Comment: Could you expand on why you can't use the object returned by merge?

Comment: The problem was resolved, i'm a freshman in sqlclchemy and i didn't know the usage of session.merge() very well.Now, i understand. Thanks for your comments. @mtth